# ValueError: Invalid field 'invoice_ids' in leaf

Tags: python, odoo

I am new in `openerp`. I have created a module `Testbase` and that is inherited `res.partner` module. I get an error when I run this module. My Python file is `testbase.py` file:

```
from openerp.osv import fields, osv, orm


def fnct(self, cr, uid, ids, fields, arg, context):
    total = {}
    for record in self.browse(cr,uid,ids):
        ac_obj = self.pool.get('account.invoice')
        ac_obj_id= ac_obj.search(cr, uid,[('invoice_id','=',record.invoice_id.id)], context=context)
        for rec in ac_obj.browse(cr,uid,ids,context=context):
            total += rec.total
    return total

class testbase(osv.osv):
     _name = 'res.partner'
     _inherit = 'res.partner'
     _columns = {
         'points' : fields.function(fnct, method=True, string='Points',type='char', readonly = True, help="it indicates to how much points a customer earned"),
     }


testbase()
```

When I run this code I receive the following error:

```
ValueError: Invalid field 'invoice_ids' in leaf "<osv.ExtendedLeaf: ('invoice_ids', 'in', [browse_record(account.invoice.line, 1)]) on account_invoice (ctx: )>"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
from openerp.osv import fields, osv, orm

def fnct(self, cr, uid, ids, fields, arg, context={}):
    total = {}
    for partner_id in ids:
        sub_total=0.0
        ac_obj = self.pool.get('account.invoice')
        ac_obj_ids= ac_obj.search(cr, uid,[('partner_id','=',partner_id)], context=context)
        for rec in ac_obj.browse(cr,uid,ac_obj_ids,context=context):
            sub_total += rec.total
        total[partner_id] = sub_total
    return total

class testbase(osv.osv):
    _name = 'res.partner'
    _inherit = 'res.partner'
    _columns = {
        'points' : fields.function(fnct, method=True, string='Points',type='char', readonly = True, help="it indicates to how much points a customer earned"),
    }
testbase()
```

Comment: thanks  @Emipro Technologies . i was make changes as yours, but when i am  the confirm sale , then i took the one customer (accounting ->customer) it raises one error "ValueError: Invalid field 'invoice_id' in leaf "<osv.ExtendedLeaf: ('invoice_id', '=', 6) on account_invoice (ctx: )>"
"

Comment: If possbile then give full debug log. It is more helpful to resolve an issue. It may happen that you have used invoice_id field some where else like in form view or search view...

Comment: thanks @Emipro Technologies , its too long so put it on as answer.

Comment: sure i will  @Emipro Technologies

Comment: According to your log, I am right. You have put one field with names "invoice_id" in your search view. It cause an error. Please remove it and just test without that field.

Comment: thanks @Emipro Technologies, its really helpful answer that you gave to me.but i didnt find "invoice_id" in my xml file. my xml file is:-  <record model="ir.ui.view" id="res_partner_form">
   <field name="name">testbase</field>
   <field name="model">res.partner</field>
   <field name="type">form</field>
   <field name="inherit_id" ref="base.view_partner_form"/>
   <field name="arch" type="xml">
    <field name="email" position="after">
    <field name="points" />
   </field>
   </field>

Comment: may i have make any changes in this xml file or make any changes to some other xml file,i mean inherited files view??

Comment: In your view you have inherited form view. But an error is comes from search view. So, please find out the field "invoice_id" in search view inside any module. After finding it just remove that field "invoice_id" and open your customer form thats it.

Comment: :- thank you , ok i will trying to find that, thanks for your support